# How to forbid angularjs $http split my array param to multiple params?

Tags: angularjs, rest

I write like this.

```
$http({
     params: {
           cql: "select * from Car where Brand in (?) and CreatedBy.obje  ctId in (?) order by updateAt desc",  
           pvalues: [["1", "2"], ["test"]]
        },
     method: "GET",
     url   : URL.CLOUD_QUERY
 });
```

But it is transformed to below when I check in chrome inspector.

```
cql:select * from Car where Brand in (?) and CreatedBy.objectId in (?) order by updateAt desc
pvalues:["1", "2"]
pvalues:["test"]
```

I don't want get two pvalues. I have a workaroud to write pvalues like this {0:[], 1:[]}, But I do not like this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it as a string and on the server side convert it back to array object.

```
$http({
     params: {
           cql: "select * from Car where Brand in (?) and CreatedBy.obje  ctId in (?) order by updateAt desc",  
           pvalues: JSON.stringify([["1", "2"], ["test"]])
        },
     method: "GET",
     url   : URL.CLOUD_QUERY
 });
```

Comment: Is this a bug or $http does this intentionally?

Comment: It is not a bug. That is how $http is supposed to pass any array input.